# Get Seller Name

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using marketplace in my website in that how to get seller Name and url

```
$collection= Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->load($sellerId,'seller_id');
```

I get Seller Id in above mention way how to get Seller Name & url

this is the field name `store_title`

Can you please suggest me how to get that

Comment: can you print the $collection data??  in that you have find out the seller name??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that module, but give this a try

```
$sellerProfile = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->load($sellerId);
```

You should be able to just load it with the ID, if that doesn't work, use your original code

```
$sellerProfile = Mage::getModel('marketplace/sellerprofile')->load($sellerId, 'seller_id');
```

Now you should be able to echo the name, which *should* be one of these:

```
echo $sellerProfile->getName();
```

Or

```
echo $sellerProfile->getSellerName();
```

If you still can't find it after that, try doing a var_dump of the model's data

```
var_dump($sellerProfile->getData());
```

If you can find what the attribute's name is, you should be able to camel-case it into a get call on the model, for example:

If you see the attribute key is 'seller_profile_name' the call would be:

```
echo $sellerProfile->getSellerProfileName();
```

Let me know how this works out for you.